# graphdb and ogma.js sample applications - where do i get commons.js?

Tags: graphdb

On this page http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/devhub/visualize.html it says:

> "All samples reuse functions from a commons.js file."

Where can i get "commmons.js" file?

I have tried deploying and running [this sample](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/devhub/related.html) and it didn't work.

Please help,
Radu

Comment: Do you have a copy of OgmaJs? On that very page you linked it is written that it'll be required to run the samples. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It's a link in the menu of the documentation named 'Common functions to visualize GraphDB data' that leads to: 
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/devhub/commons.html

Comment: @NicoHaase Both the question and the answer are linked on the referred pages, above/below each other. OP should have checked the navigation pane as the answer points out too.